# MasOS удаление NGINX

Tags: nginx, macos, apache2

Пытаюсь удалить NGINX выдаёт ошибку:

```
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/nginx
```

Делал все что возможно:

$ > brew uninstall ngnix  - команда выполнилась, ошибка.

```
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/nginx
```

$ > brew uninstall ngnix --force - команда выполнилась, ошибок небыло.

```
$ >
```

$ > brew remove ngnix  - команда выполнилась, ошибка.

```
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/nginx
```

$ > brew remove ngnix --force - команда выполнилась, ошибок небыло.

```
$ >
```

Вывожу список установленных продуктов через `brew list`

```
...
mysql
neovim
node
oniguruma
...
```

То есть nginx нету и все вроде бы хорошо, но открывая `http://localhost:8080` или `http://localhost` попадаем на страницу
**Welcome to ngixn**

Ввожу команду `which nginx`

```
nginx not found
```

Видел советы удалить все папки связанные с NGIXN

```
rm -f -R /usr/local/nginx
rm -f /usr/local/sbin/nginx
rm -r /usr/local/var/run/nginx
rm -f -R /usr/local/etc/nginx  
rm -r /usr/local/opt/nginx
```

эффекта нету

Comment: А выключить-то nginx не забыли? Может, просто перезагрузитесь?

Comment: @andreymal, перезагружался, сервис отключал и проделавал те же самые шаги вновь, но итог это не изменило

Comment: Тогда глупый вопрос - а это точно nginx, а не страница из кэша браузера?

Comment: вы везде пишете `brew ... ngnix`, но ведь nginx название пакета

Comment: `ls -la /opt/homebrew/opt/ | grep nginx` так что печатает?